# SSMS - Collapse Query Code at open by default?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a Query with a few exceptionally [for me] long sections [Insert Into @TableName ...]. When I open the Query, these sections have minus signs in little squares to the left of the 'Insert Into ...' statements:
[-] Insert Into ...
so I can collapse the sections I am not actually working in at the time.

Is it possible to have the query [or all my queries in SSMS] open with the various sections collapsed - by default?

I hope I have laid out my question clearly.

Thanks!!

Comment: Shortcut: CTRL+M, CTRL+A and CTRL+M, CTRL+X to expand

Comment: @lad2025: Perhaps I should have mentioned that I am using SQL Server 2012? I tried Your suggestion and the result was - nothing happened when I pressed Ctrl+M - and pressing Ctrl+A after that selected all the text in the query ... ? When I pressed Ctrl+M and then Ctrl+X - all the text in the query was deleted.

Comment: Doesn't matter. SQL Server is server side, SSMS is client tool. SSMS version matters and you should use newest 17.3

Comment: Sorry. I am using SSMS 11.0.6248.0. I'm not sure I have the option to get the latest version of SSMS. Is it free?

Comment: Yes it is free: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: Thanks! I'll explore this with my employer. 'Free' makes it a definite maybe!! :D

Comment: You could download it on personal computer, test shortcuts and tell me that if my comment should be posted as answer